# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered for text Values

Tags: php, html, ajax, web, web-deployment

I'm really new to this and was working on this homework where I was supposed to create a drop-down list for the writers in my database and as the user hovers over one of the authors the books that they wrote would show in an area on the same page, now I tried all I knew but I keep getting this error.

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\books.php on line 21

even though the data in my database is all text, no need for any numeric values.

I submitted the assignment just like that but I still want to know what I did wrong, I would really appreciate the help

```
            <?php

              $servername = "localhost";
              $username = "root";
              $password = "";
              $dbname = "books";

                 // variables used in script
              $Author =$_REQUEST["Author"];



                       // Create connection
                        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                       // Check connection
                       if (!$conn) {
                           die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                       }

                       $sql = "SELECT BookName, BookID FROM `books`"+ 'WHERE AuthorName='+ '"'+'$Author'+'"';
            $sqlData=    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


                if($sqlData)

                {
                while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlData)){
                   echo" <table style='width:100%'>"+ "<tr> <th>BookName</th> <th>BookID</th> <th>AuthorName</th> </tr>"+"<tr> <td>"+ $row[BookName] +
                 "</td><td>"+$row[BookID] +"</td> </tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>" ;

                }





           ?>
```

this is the whole code where my drop down list is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>


                    <html>
                       <head>
                          <meta charset = "utf-8">
                          <title>Books</title>
                          <style >
                             label  { width: 5em; float: left; }
                          </style>



                                <script  >

                                function ShowBook_Info(Author) {
                                    request=new XMLHttpRequest();
                                    request.onreadystatechange=function() {
                                        if (request.readyState==4 && request.status==200) {
                                            document.getElementById("books").innerHTML=request.responseText;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    request.open("GET","books.php?Author="+Author,true);
                                    request.send();
                                }

                            </script>


                       </head>

                           <?php

                          $servername = "localhost";
                          $username = "root";
                          $password = "";
                          $dbname = "books";



                             $sql="SELECT AuthorName FROM `books`";

                                   // Create connection
                                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                                   // Check connection
                                   if (!$conn) {
                                       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                                   }



                               $sqlData=    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                               if($sqlData){



                                   echo "<select  onchange='ShowBook_Info(this.value)'>" ;
                                   while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlData)){
                                       $Value=$row["AuthorName"];
                                       echo "<option value=";
                                       echo '$value'.'">';
                                       echo $row["AuthorName"];
                                       echo "</option>";


                                   }
                                   echo "</select>" ;


                               } else {
                                   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                               }



                       ?>


                        <body  onload="ShowBook_Info('Harper Lee');" >



                              <div style="color:blue;" id='books'>
                     This is a test text

                     </div>

                          </form>
                       </body>
                    </html>
```

Comment: `+` is _not_ the string concatenation operator in PHP.

Comment: `.` is. But you should know that since you used it in ` . mysqli_connect_error())`.

Comment: Interesting, who placed a close vote for `opinion based` :)

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's opinion based if you want `"text"."text"` or `"text" . "text"` :-)

Answer (score -1):

you have many error in your code.
Please check the syntax of php to better understand coding on php

`$sql = "SELECT BookName, BookID FROM`books`"+ 'WHERE AuthorName='+ '"'+'$Author'+'"';`

the `AuthorName='+ '"'+'$Author'+'"';` its not right. just simple use. 
`AuthorName='{$Author}'"; and the full will be  like:

`$sql = "SELECT BookName, BookID FROM`books` WHERE AuthorName='{$Author}' ";

`$row[BookName]` => `$row['BookName']` or `$row["BookName"]`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't understand what are you saying. Did you read the comment or what is your attention ?